# Explanation for stability criterium microwave amplifiers

Tags: amplifier, stability, microwave

Given a general microwave amplifier circuit
[image: Amplifier circuit]

For this amplifier (transistor) to be stable the the magnitude of the input and output reflection coefficient must be smaller than 1.

[image: Stability conditions]

But why? What is an intuitive explanation for why the magnitude of the input and output reflections need to be smaller than 1 for this amplifier to be stable?

Answer (score 1):

Reflection coefficient is the ratio, reflected/transmitted. If your input refection coef. is >1, you could supply the amp with 1 watt and have 2 watts reflected back out to the input port. If it continues to reflect back and forth, with the magnitude increasing with each reflection, you have an oscillation.